# In AnyLogic, how do you dynamically define batch sizes that are not predefined?

Tags: anylogic

The situation is as follows:

Source ---> Batch (random size) ---> Unbatch ---> Select Output (80%) ---> Batch agents from True Port and Batch agents from False Port.

An example with numbers is a batch of 50 agents. After unbatching, 38 go through the True Port while 12 go through the False port. So the new batch sizes need to be 38 and 12 respectively. It is important to note that the 50 will change with every batch, so we cannot know the new batch sizes until they go through the Select Output.

So, in summary, how can this scenario be modeled in AnyLogic? Is there a function that can do that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a blog post about this topic you can read here: https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches/

The idea is to combine a wait block with a batch block.

When your agents come out of the selectoutput they will get to a wait block where they will wait for all associated agents to arrive, when the last one arrives, you will define the batch size of the subsequent batch block and free all the agents that need to be batched.

so when the last agent from the original batch gets to the wait block, you will free the agents in both wait blocks so you need to know how many agents were in the original batch and the number of agents present in each of the 2 wait blocks.

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Felipe. Interesting approach.